# UIWebview loadRequest not working only in iPhone X

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load a URL using webView in Objective C. I tried "https://www.tidecleaners.com/cincinati-pricing" and it works fine for all devices. But not working only in iPhone X.

Here its my code,

```
NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.tidecleaners.com/cincinati-pricing";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.WebView_O.delegate = self;
[self.WebView_O loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: are you got any console reprt

Comment: Can you tell us what is the exact issue or give us logs for error. Thanks

Comment: Why not use `WKWebView`? According to Apple docs: Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Comment: I faced "NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1007" this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlerrorhttptoomanyredirects), error -1007 means `NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects`, i.e. the HTTP connection failed due to too many redirects.
Maybe the WebView implementation of the iOS version on your iPhone X is less tolerant to redirects than on older devices. However, this seems to be a server issue, and you probably won't be able to do much about it on the client side.

However, to get more information about the issue, you can enable a more verbose network log:

- Open your scheme in Xcode.
- Select `Run`on the left, and the `Arguments` tab on the right.
- Add `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` to the environment variables, and add 1, 2, or 3 as a value (depending on the verbosity you want).

[image]

Hopefully, the logs will then tell you a bit more about the error.